# Insert delimiter between digits in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have few random numbers which I retrieve from a database. Eg.

```
12203770
6458251
6458250
10336719
10366878
10366877
10366874
81048
```

Now, I have to place the delimiter "/" in between them. I am using this command:

```
[root@abc01 ~]#  awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS="/"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' /tmp/abc.txt
```

This works fine if numbers are 8 digits but my `requirement` is :
The command/script should leave last 3 digit from right and for rest, it prints digit with delimiter.

Desired output required:

```
1/2/2/0/3
6/4/5/8
6/4/5/8
1/0/3/3/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
8/1
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you explain why the expected output for `6458251` (`6/4/5/8`) is different from the expected output for `6458250` (`6/4/5/8/`)?

Comment: `sed -e 's|\(.\)|\1/|g;s|\(.*\)/\(.\/\)\{3\}|\1|g' /tmp/abc.txt`

Comment: @Simon apologies, it was a typo. I will edit the changes.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Although, the answers are helpful but these doesn't work if I have numbers less than 3 in the input. say: 123,234 etc. If the numbers are less than 3 then code should print only "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS="/"}{NF-=3;print}' file
1/2/2/0/3
6/4/5/8
6/4/5/8
1/0/3/3/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
8/1
```

Comment: You should mention that will only work in some awks (e.g. gawk) due to 1) Setting `FS=""` resulting in the input being split into characters and 2) Decrementing `NF` resulting in fields being deleted. Neither thing is POSIX.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/./,"&/"); sub(/.{7}$/,"")} 1' file
1/2/2/0/3
6/4/5/8
6/4/5/8
1/0/3/3/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
8/1

$ sed 's#.#&/#g; s#.\{7\}$##' file
1/2/2/0/3
6/4/5/8
6/4/5/8
1/0/3/3/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
1/0/3/6/6
8/1
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight why would you make that comment under this extremely simple, 100% portable answer using absolutely basic substitutions (it doesn't get much simpler than `s/old/new`!) rather than the other answer which uses cryptic, non-portable, non-obvious sleight-of-hand? If anyone doesn't understand this answer then a very quick glance at google or a man page will explain it and the person researching it will learn more than if I explain what s/old/new means but if anyone has ever used sed or awk for anything at all then they'll understand these scripts at a glance.

Comment: @EdMorton Although, the answers are helpful but these doesn't work if I have numbers less than 3 in the input. say: 123,234 etc. If the numbers are less than 3 then code should print only "/".

Comment: @sumitgupta this is why it's important for you to put effort into coming up with sample input that covers your use cases, so you don't waste peoples time coming up with and testing answers that do what you said you wanted when run against what we expect to be truly representative sample data you provided for us to test with but don't work against your real data because you didn't represent your real data with your sample input/output. How could we possibly guess that your real data might have 3 or less digits or more importantly what the output should be in that case? Good luck!

Comment: @EdMorton I understand. However, in initial cases I have never come across the numbers less than 3. Now, I do. I wasn't able to rectify the same. Hence, asked the solution reverting here.
Later, I realized this particular question is in resolved state (as per earlier requirement) so I should ask a different question mentioning about revised criteria. Now, can you tell me where did I go possibly wrong?

Comment: You should have thought more about the potential edge cases of your problem instead of just throwing out some sample of cases you just happened to have lying around. You want to delete 3 chars and apparently have no requirement that your input is always longer than 3 chars - you should have thought of that, it's a very obvious test case if it can happen and you had no indication it couldn't happen. If this requirements "change" **was** completely out of the blue then you should simply have opened a new question referring to this one instead of leaving comments here expecting us to rework it.

Comment: @EdMorton Point taken. Next time I shall keep in mind all these tips.