# insert symbol between numbers

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file in Linux OS containing some random numbers:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
```

Now, I have two conditions:
 1. Remove last 3 digit from every entry and put `/` in between rest. 
 2. For the numbers <=3, just add/replace with `/` symbol.

command I am trying which fulfilling only 1st requirement is:

```
 sed -e 's|\(.\)|\1/|g;s|\(.*\)/\(.\/\)\{3\}|\1|g'
```

Desired out required:

```
/
/
/
4
5/5
6/6/6
7/7/7/7
8/8/8/8/8
```

Please help.

Comment: Downvoted because it was asked previously at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37247248/1745001 then abandoned for a month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
% sed 's/.\{1,3\}$//;s/./\/&/g;s/.//;s/^$/\//' file
/
/
/
4
5/5
6/6/6
7/7/7/7
8/8/8/8/8
```

No smart moves here:

```
s/.\{1,3\}$//; # Remove last 3 character
s/./\/&/g;     # Insert / before each character
s/.//;         # Remove first character (it's now a /)
s/^$/\//       # Insert slash on all empty lines
```

Alternative solution with gawk:

```
awk -v FS='' -v OFS='/' '{if (NF > 3) NF=(NF-3); else $0 = OFS}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.{1,3}$//;s#\B#/#g' file
```

Remove the last three (or less) characters from the end of the line. Replace the void between characters with `/`'s.